# Is it better to hold tax-inefficient investments in tax-deferred versus tax-free accounts?

Tags: taxes, investing

[This page](http://www.bogleheads.org/wiki/Principles_of_tax-efficient_fund_placement) seems to suggest it is preferable to hold tax-inefficient investments in tax-deferred versus tax-free accounts. Is there an explanation for this? Holding tax-efficient investments in taxable accounts is obvious but tax-deferred versus tax-free is not to me. Are there any simulations comparing the two?

Comment: Where on that page does it say to use tax-deferred rather than tax-free?

Comment: I don't think it explicitly says that, but based on the vertical order of the the accounts on the right side of the figure [here](http://www.bogleheads.org/wiki/Principles_of_tax-efficient_fund_placement#Step_2:_Place_your_least_tax_efficient_funds_first) that was my assumption. If they were equivalent I would expect them to be placed side by side, or only have one box labeled "tax-advantaged accounts".

Comment: The "if good fund choices available" on that diagram makes me think that it's using "tax-deferred" to refer to a 401k where you can only choose from the funds available by the 401k provider your employer has chosen.

Comment: That is my interpretation as well. I'm just wondering, let's say my 401(k) has great bond fund options. Should I hold all my bonds in there and none in my Roth IRA, and if so why? Or does it not make a difference?

Comment: I would guess it's the same reason to use the 401k in general (employer match and higher contrib limits); see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The "if good fund choices available" on that diagram makes me think that it's using "tax-deferred" to refer to a 401k where you can only choose from the funds available by the 401k provider your employer has chosen.  (This may be a slight inconsistency with how "tax-deferred" is used elsewhere on the page.)  If it were just a generic tax-deferred account that you fully controlled, you could decide what bank to hold it at and thus pick whatever funds you wanted.  So I think what it's saying is "if you have good but tax-inefficient fund choices available through your 401k (which happens to be tax-deferred rather than tax-free), put your tax-inefficient assets there".

Given that it was a 401k, the reasons to put your bond fund in there rather than the Roth IRA are the same reasons to prefer a 401k over an individual IRA/Roth in general: you are likely to get an employer match and you can potentially contribute more than the the IRA contribution limits.

Comment: "which happens to be tax-deferred rather than tax-free" Well, Traditional 401k is tax-deferred; Roth 401k is tax-free.

Answer (score 0):

Given these below assumptions I would believe that it would make sense to put your least-tax efficient investments in the tax-deferred.
**Assumptions**

- Tax inefficient investments perform slightly worse than its more tax
  efficient equivalent (IE: High turnover Active funds vs Active funds)
- Comparing Roth IRA vs 401k

Reasoning behind bullet one is that you would want to place your higher growth funds into tax free accounts versus the tax deferred accounts.
Given bullet two, you may not have the investment options available in your 401k account, which generally more restrictive.  Strangely many 401k accounts tend to have a REIT option.

Comment: But there's Traditional IRA, Roth IRA, Traditional 401k, and Roth 401k. Traditional is tax-deferred, and Roth is tax-free. Why arbitrarily Roth IRA and Traditional 401k? It would be confounding the tax-deferred vs. tax-free issue with the IRA vs 401k issue.

Comment: That assumption was just based on the article OP cited.